# How to scroll through a google sheet using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that will be mirrored on a wall monitor for information presentation purposes.

The sheet has like 1000 rows to be displayed. How can I write with JavaScript the sheet to scroll through all rows slowly from top to bottom & continue to reiterate as an infinite loop?

Comment: Just as you would do with any other page. Have you tired searching SO for `scroll with JavaScript`?

Comment: Have you tried checking this [SO post](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action)?

Comment: Please explain how this SO post is the solution to the question?